# jquery transform fails below parent level. Why? What do I do?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The following code should wrap the images with , but it doesn't and I'm stumped. Could it be because I have used getJSOndata?

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Working With JSON</title>
        <style>
        #content {
          padding: 5pt;
          border: 2px dashed lightgray;
        }
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
          $("document").ready(function() {
            getJSONData();
            addDIV();
            jQuery('img', '#content').attr("alt","noddy");        
          });
```

Call for images.

```
        function getJSONData() {
        var flickrAPI = "http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?jsoncallback=?";
        $.getJSON( flickrAPI, {
              tags: "space needle",
              tagmode: "any",
              format: "json"
              },
            successFn);
          }
```

create HTML for images.

```
          function successFn(result) {
            $.each(result.items, function(i, item) {
             $("<img>").attr({"src":item.media.m, "alt":"gallery"}).appendTo("#content");
            if (i === 4) {
              return false;
             }
           });
          }
```

Here is an illustration of the problem.
I can add a tag to the parent (div)
but I can't add a tag to the child.

```
          function addDIV () {
            // put each image within it's own div
            // select all images 
            // this works
            $('#content').wrap("<DIV></DIV>");
            // this doesn't work
            $('#content img').wrap("<DIV></DIV>");
            // Why ???
            }
      </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h1>Working With Different Data Types</h1>
    <div id="content"></div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should run the **addDIV** function inside the callback function **successFn**:

```
function successFn(result) {
    $.each(result.items, function(i, item) {
        $("<img>").attr({"src":item.media.m, "alt":"gallery"}).appendTo("#content");
        if (i === 4) {
           return false;
        }
    });
    addDiv();
}
```

Keep in mind that your using an Ajax request which is asynchronous by default, meaning that the Javascript execution is going to continue even if the callback response is not executed yet, in the code below, **addDiv()** is going to be executed before the callback **successFn()**.

```
$("document").ready(function() {
    getJSONData();
    addDIV();
    jQuery('img', '#content').attr("alt","noddy");        
});
```